# Extract Meta itemprop="price" content

Tags: php, metadata, meta

A given URL has code :-

```
  <meta itemprop="price" content="12.00" />
```

I want to extract 12 to a new variable, I have no idea from where to begin because here we cannot use Tags PHP function which is used to extract normal meta tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get all meta tags you should make use of  XPath to select all nodes

```
$xmlsource = 'http://www.example.com/';
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($xmlsource);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
//find all elements with itemprop attribute
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop]');  
foreach ($nodes as $node) { 

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php):

```
$string  = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
//get all meta tags
$el = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');

echo'<pre>';
print_r($el);
echo'</pre>';

foreach($el as $val){
    //get value of each content
    echo $val -> getAttribute('content').'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPath filter would be 
//meta[@itemprop='price']/@content

if you were in Google Sheets you could use the importXML formula as follows....

=importxml("http://www.example.com/product-specific-url-here", "//meta[@itemprop='price']/@content")

Is that what you were looking for?